# Xcode: Could not launch “WebDriverAgentRunner_tvOS”

Tags: xcode, react-native, appium, tvos, automation-testing

Hi I was facing this issue since a week, I tried all the options but no use, can someone help me please..!! I'm totally blocked.
Could not launch “WebDriverAgentRunner_tvOS”
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. Cound not find any application for open app system request <FBSystemServiceOpenApplicationRequest: 0x282909e60; trusted: YES; bundleID: com.facebook.mm13.xcui.WebDriverAgentRunner.xctrunner; client: anon:664>

```
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-07-18 23:42:12 +0000";
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    RawUnderlyingErrorMessage = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. Cound not find any application for open app system request <FBSystemServiceOpenApplicationRequest: 0x282909e60; trusted: YES; bundleID: com.facebook.mm13.xcui.WebDriverAgentRunner.xctrunner; client: anon:664>";
}
```

--

```
Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "AppleTV5,3";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.4.1 (19L452)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.appletvos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Test;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 9344;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 4;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.appletvos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 0;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 3;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 0;
    "param_install_style" = 2;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_type" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 1;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "appletvos15.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.4";
    "sdk_variant" = appletvos;
}
```

--
System Information
macOS Version 12.4 (Build 21F79)
Xcode 13.4.1 (20504) (Build 13F100)
Timestamp: 2022-07-18T23:42:12Z
Xcode

Xcode Server

Xcode Sanitizers and Runtime Issues

Comment: Could you add a bit more context on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: We are trying to build WebdriverAgent_Runner for the tvOS device, so it will interact with Appium and our App while running tests.